# Can I read stored SMS entries on my Windows Mobile phone from a .NET CF application?

Tags: .net, compact-framework, sms

Looking at writing an application using the .NET Compact framework to extract SMS messages on my Windows Mobile phone.  I basically want to be able to export the stored message in the inbox so that they could be imported to Excel or some other program for formatting and storage.

In my personal case, I have a Treo 700w.  I've written some small apps under the Compact Framework before, but I can't find anything referencing where the text messages are stored.  I have some 7000 messages stored in my phone and I'd like to extract them to free up memory.  I may have to keep these messages around for legal reasons so I'd like to preserve them 'offline' as far as my phone is concerned.

Has anyone ever had to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are targeting WM6, you can use the Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook namespace to access SMS messages, particularly the [SmsAccount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.smsaccount.aspx) class.

Comment: Well, the phone I have is never going to see WM6 but my next one should.  I may just end up delaying writing this application until I upgrade and leave the old phone 'as is' with the messages in it.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the .NET Framework (compact or otherwise) includes an API for working with SMS which is done through [CE MAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb415647.aspx). In other words you'll have to use interop, or write the app in C++. 
Or if you're lazy you can just use [a wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/PocketPCandSmartphone.aspx). =)